# $R^{3}$ is open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have thought about 2 ways to prove this, but there are not complete. What should I add to finish the proof?

Proof 1: For all $x\in \mathbb{R^{3}}$ there is $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset \mathbb{R^{3}}$

any $r>0$ will satisfy the requirement because $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ is dense? which arguments about $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ can I use.

And therefore $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ is open

On the other hand A=$\mathbb{R^{3}}\setminus \mathbb{R^{3}}=\emptyset$ and the empty set is open and closed so $A$ is open (and closed?)

Proof 2: Every limit point of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are contained in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ so $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ is closed.
which facts on the limit points can I use to prove it is open?

Comment: The corresponsiding claim holds for *any* metric space $X$, i.e., $\emptyset$ and $X$ are both open and closed. Hence you need no density argument nor any other special property of $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: If R^3 is the entire set, then it is certainly open. It is also closed because the empty set is also open.  One of the axioms of a collection T of subsets of a set X to be a topology is that both X and the empty set are members of T, that is, they are both open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right when you say that

$$A=\mathbb R^3\setminus \mathbb R^3=\emptyset$$

is open and closed.

With this argument you can conclude that $\mathbb R^3$ is closed and open.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Then, for all $\varepsilon >0$, $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ By contradiction. Suposse that exist $x\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ such that $x\notin\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then, $x\in{\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus\mathbb{R}^{3}}=\emptyset$. Clearly this is a contradiction.

Now, since $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is open, $\emptyset$ is closed.

In the other way, we want to prove that $\emptyset$ is open, i.e., if a $x\in\emptyset$, then exist $\delta>0$ such that $B_{\delta}{x}\subset\emptyset$. This is true by emptiness. Then, $\emptyset$ is open and his complemente $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is closed.